# How to execute one function with different timeouts in node.js 4.2.3

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a newbie in JavaScript and node.js, so my question could be pretty stupid, but i try.

I was reading a lot about timeouts, closures and so on, but I am stuck. I want make pretty simple thing: I have the array of objects and want to run one function for all it element after **different** timeout. For example, 3 second for first, 5 second for second, and so on. How can I achieve this?

I wrote some test code (for simplify with one timeout, but i still need different timeouts - instead of "i" will be objects with their own properties, including timeout):

```
"use strict";
function test(i) {
    console.log('%d', i);
}
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    setTimeout(test(i), 1000);
    console.log('here');
}
```

Output:

```
D:\Projects\js_projects>node timeout.js
<< why there is no 1000 ms delay here?
0
here
1
here
2
here
3
here
4
here
```

With no delay between start and first element output (why?).

I expect such output:

```
here
here
here
here
here
<1000 ms delay here>
0
1
2
3
4
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because of `setTimeout(test(i), 1000)`. You are actually **calling** the function. What you need to do is just pass a reference to the function, like:

```
setTimeout(test, 1000); // test function will be executed after 1000ms
```

More information for [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

If you want to call multiple functions with that loop, you should use something like:

```
setTimeout(test, 1000 + (i * 100)); // 1000ms + 100ms per each i
```

If you got 5 loops, they will be called at: 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400.

If you want to pass some parameter to that function, use the third argument:

```
setTimeout(test, 1000 + (i * 100), i);
```

`i` will be passed to the function so you can actually use it.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I am using JSLint.Net for checking my code, but it is far from c++ compiler. I can't imagine that somebody can use setTimeout in such way, so it would be very cool if JSLint warn me about the mistake, but it prohibit me to using ++i in 'for' cycles instead :(